# Does association in rails generated automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have command and model like this:

Command

```rb
$ bin/rails generate model User name:string firstname:string

$ bin/rails genarate model Profile username:string password:string
```

model generated by rails

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
end

Class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Is the 1:1 association in migrate folder generated automatically by rails or I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) does not create database columns automatically. That would actually be a very risky and undesirable feature. You do not want your Rails server to change the DB schema at runtime. Thats what migrations are for.

You can however use the [`references`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-references) "type" in the generators (also aliased as `belongs_to`) which creates a a foreign key column as well as an assocation in the model:

```bash
bin/rails g model Profile username:string password:string user:references
```

```ruby
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```ruby
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

There is no equivilent for adding `has_one` or `has_many` assocations from generators as they don't actually correspond to a database column on *this* model.

If you need to add a foreign key column to the table after the fact you do it by generating a migration:

```bash
bin/rails g migration AddUserIdToProfiles user:refereces
```

Comment: So how to apply this in the model and the database? ```bin/rails g migration AddUserIdToProfiles user:refereces```

Comment: Ooh I got this, I just need to read the doc Add UserId To Profiles

Comment: You just run the migration with `rails db:migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

The migration file for Profiles (`class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration`) should have a foreign key declaration like this:

`t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true`

whole code:

```
create_table :profiles do |t|
  t.string :username
  t.string :password
  t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps
end
```

That can also be generated automaticaly with the generator command by adding `user:references` like so:
`$ bin/rails genarate model Profile username:string password:string user:references`

You can also refer to the [Active Record Migrations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) guide and search for "references" on that page.